# view User model under Teacher model in admin page which has one to one relation with User in Django

Tags: python, django, model, django-templates

Here is models.py file.
here Teacher has a foreign key relation with User.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
import misaka
from departments.models import Department

teacher_rank = [
    ("Lecturer", "Lecturer"),
    ("Assistant professor", "Assistant professor"),
    ("Associate professor", "Associate professor"),
    ("Professor", "Professor"),
    ("Professor emeritus", "Professor emeritus"),
]

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,blank=False, related_name="teachers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='teachers/profile_pics', blank=True)
    Teacher_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False)
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    academic_rank = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, choices=teacher_rank)
    teacher_slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.teacher_slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("teachers:teacher_detail",
                        kwargs={"department_slug":self.department.department_slug,
                            "teacher_slug":self.teacher_slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["Teacher_ID"]
        unique_together = ["Teacher_ID", "department"]
```

Here the details of teacher model is viewed under User model in admin page of django.
admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Register your models here.
from .models import Teacher

class TeacherInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Teacher
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = "teacher"
    fk_name = 'user'

class TeacherAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (TeacherInline, )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(TeacherAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, TeacherAdmin)
```

As the code is implemented, teacher details is shown under User section in admin site.
What i want is to view user details under Teacher section

Comment: i haven't got any solve of this problem

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: i think this can't be done using django

Comment: can anybody suggest me another way

Comment: looks like i have to skip this without any solution